# Combine 2 complex queries into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to combine these 2 queries into a single one. I've run into the limits of what I know and can't figure out if this is possible or not.

**This is the 1st query that gets last year sales for each day per location (for one month):**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#LY_Data') is not null drop table #LY_Data
select  
    [LocationId]            = ri.LocationId,
    [LY_Date]               = convert(date, ri.ReceiptDate),
    [LY_Trans]              = count(distinct ri.SalesReceiptId),
    [LY_SoldQty]            = convert(money, sum(ri.Qty)),
    [LY_RetailAmount]       = convert(money, sum(ri.ExtendedPrice)),
    [LY_NetSalesAmount]     = convert(money, sum(ri.ExtendedAmount))
into #LY_Data
from rpt.SalesReceiptItem ri
join #Location l
    on ri.LocationId = l.Id
where ri.Ignored = 0
    and ri.LineType = 1 /*Item*/
    and ri.ReceiptDate between @_LYDateFrom and @_LYDateTo
group by 
    ri.LocationId, 
    ri.ReceiptDate
```

**Then the 2nd query computes a ratio based on the total sales for that month for each day (to be used later):**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#LY_Data2') is not null drop table #LY_Data2
select 
    [LocationId]            = ly.LocationId,
    [LY_Date]               = ly.LY_Date,
    [LY_Trans]              = ly.LY_Trans,
    [LY_RetailAmount]       = ly.LY_RetailAmount,
    [LY_NetSalesAmount]     = ly.LY_NetSalesAmount,
    [Ratio]                 = ly.LY_NetSalesAmount / t.MonthlySales
into #LY_Data2
from ( 
        select
            [LocationId]        = ly.LocationId,
            [MonthlySales]      = sum(ly.LY_NetSalesAmount)
        from #LY_Data ly
        group by
            ly.LocationId
) t
join #LY_Data ly
    on t.LocationId = ly.LocationId
```

I've tried using the first query as a subquery in the 2nd query group-by from clause, but that won't let me select those columns in the outer most select statement (multi part identifier couldn't be bound).

As well as putting the first query into the join clause at the end of the 2nd query with the same issue.

There's probably something I'm missing, but I'm still pretty new to SQL so any help or just a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: So you are just trying to avoid using the #LY_Data temp table?  Or is there some other problem with the query?

Comment: Does the 1 query solution still have to insert it all into #LY_Data2?

Comment: @ElementZero I'd like to have a single temp table. As #LY_Data2 is the same as #LY_Data, just with another computed column. The code works as intended right now, but I wondering if there's a more simple/elegant solution.

Comment: @MartinNavarro a 1 query solution will just insert into the #LY_Data temp table. I'm trying to avoid using 2 temp tables in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#LY_Data') is not null drop table #LY_Data

;with
    cte AS
    (
        select  
            [LocationId]            = ri.LocationId,
            [LY_Date]               = convert(date, ri.ReceiptDate),
            [LY_Trans]              = count(distinct ri.SalesReceiptId),
            [LY_SoldQty]            = convert(money, sum(ri.Qty)),
            [LY_RetailAmount]       = convert(money, sum(ri.ExtendedPrice)),
            [LY_NetSalesAmount]     = convert(money, sum(ri.ExtendedAmount))
        from rpt.SalesReceiptItem ri
        join #Location l
            on ri.LocationId = l.Id
        where ri.Ignored = 0
            and ri.LineType = 1 /*Item*/
            and ri.ReceiptDate between @_LYDateFrom and @_LYDateTo
        group by 
            ri.LocationId, 
            ri.ReceiptDate
    )

select
    [LocationId]        = cte.LocationId,
    [LY_Date]           = cte.LY_Date,
    ...
    [Ratio]             = cte.LY_NetSalesAmount / sum(cte.LY_NetSalesAmount) over (partition by cte.LocationId)
into #LY_Data
from cte
```

`sum(cte.LY_NetSalesAmount) over (partition by cte.LocationId)` gives you the sum for each `locationId`. The code assume that this sum is always non-zero. Otherwise, a divide-by-0 error will occur.

Comment: +1 & if you use the window function - thus removing the need for the join - you can do without the CTE and instead use a simple subquery.

Comment: I agree, but if I didn't know about CTEs or window functions then I might be overwhelmed putting both into a single query ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That works! I was aware of CTE's but have never used them so I wasn't sure how to get started with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to do is calculate `ratio` in the first query.

You can do this with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
...
convert(money, sum(ri.ExtendedAmount)/(SELECT sum(ri2.ExtendedAmount)
                                       FROM rpt.SalesReceiptItem ri2
                                       WHERE ri2.LocationId=ri.LocationId
                                      )
) AS ratio  --extended amount/total extended amount for this location
```

Comment: That wouldn't exactly work though. 'SalesReceiptItem' doesn't have aggregate data, so you're basically dividing the same values by each other as the WHERE clause doesn't really do anything.

Comment: It's not correct that the WHERE clause doesn't do anything.  The WHERE clause specifies that the subquery returns the entire SUM(extended amount) for the related location.   The outer query is grouped by location and receipt date.   The subquery is only "grouped" by location.   Did you not notice the use of the SUM() function in the subquery?   There's your aggregation.

Comment: That's what I though, but when ran against the data it produced much smaller values than expected from the original 2-query results or the CTE answer here.